# Redux-Form clears existing form properties from state after change of route

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have React application in which I am using Redux to manage application state. There are mutltiple reducers which is custom created and I have forms too in my application. To maintain form state I have used redux-form library and its working fine but whenever I submit the form and move to next route, the state for previous route form gets removed from redux form property.

store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'
import { CountHandler, ProgressbarHandler } from "./reducers/Reducer";

const RootStore = combineReducers({
    form: formReducer,
    Counter:CountHandler,
    Progress: ProgressbarHandler,
})

const store = createStore(RootStore)

export default store;
```

Route1.js

```
import {React, useState} from 'react'
import { TitleOptions } from '../../data/title'
import Button from '../../components/form-feilds/button/Button'
import Dropdown from '../../components/form-feilds/dropdown/Dropdown'
import Input from '../../components/form-feilds/input/Input';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import ApplicantPreview from './ApplicantPreview';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function ApplicantForm(props) {
    let formProperties = {
        lblTitle: "Your title",
        lblFirstName: "Enter your first name",
        lblLastName: "Enter your last name",
        submitButtonText: "Next",
        dropdownOptions: TitleOptions
    }

    let isBack = useSelector((state) => state.BackJourney)
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    return (
        <div className="container bupa-container page-form-wrapper">
            <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit((data) => navigate('/quote-cover-for'))}>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-7 col-sm-12 col-lg-2 grid-cust-pad">
                        <Field name="ApplicantTitle" inputProps={{dropdownLabelClass: 'input-label', dropdownLabel:formProperties.lblTitle, dropdownFieldClass:'form-control', options:formProperties.dropdownOptions}} component={Dropdown} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-5 grid-cust-pad">
                        <Field name="ApplicantFirstName" value="Test" inputProps={{inputLabel:formProperties.lblFirstName, inputLabelClass:'input-label', inputFieldType:'text', inputFieldClass:'form-control'}} component={Input} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-5 grid-cust-pad">
                        <Field name="ApplicantLastName" inputProps={{inputLabel:formProperties.lblFirstName, inputLabelClass:'input-label', inputFieldType:'text', inputFieldClass:'form-control'}} component={Input} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="col-12 text-center">
                        <Button buttonType="submit" buttonText={formProperties.submitButtonText} buttonClass="btn btn-primary btn-chevron-next mt-30" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default reduxForm({
    form:'applicantForm'
})(ApplicantForm)
```

Route2.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { CoverForOptions } from '../../data/CoverFor';
import Button from '../../components/form-feilds/button/Button';
import Dropdown from '../../components/form-feilds/dropdown/Dropdown';
import Counter from '../../components/form-feilds/counter/Counter';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

function CoverSelectForm(props) {
    let formProperties = {
        lblTitle: "Select Rider",
        submitButtonText: "Next",
        backButtonText: "Back",
        options: CoverForOptions
    }

    return (
        <div className="page-form-wrapper">
            <form>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <Field name="CoverType" inputProps={{dropdownLabelClass:"input-label", dropdownLabel:formProperties.lblTitle, dropdownFieldClass:"form-control", options:formProperties.options}} component={Dropdown} />
                        
                    </div>

                    <div
                     className="col-12 text-center">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-link btn-chevron-prev mt-30" onClick={GoBack}>Back</button>
                        <Button buttonType="submit" buttonText={formProperties.submitButtonText} buttonClass="btn btn-primary btn-chevron-next mt-30" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default reduxForm({
    form:'coverSelectForm'
})(CoverSelectForm)
```